# Determining the limit of $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \ln(x^2+y^2)$ as $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I want to evaluate the limit of $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\ln(x^2+y^2)$ as $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$. Using polar coordinates, $x=r \cos \theta$, $y= r \sin \theta$, I obtain $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\ln(x^2+y^2)=2r\ln(r)$ but I can not understand why this would be more simple than the original expression, or how I can proceed with this problem.

Comment: Tip: You can use $\LaTeX$ in titles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach with polar coordinates is correct. The limit $\lim_{r\to 0^+}2r\ln(r)$ is simpler than the given one because it is a one-variable limit. One way to evaluate it is to write $2r\ln(r)$ as $\frac{2\ln(r)}{1/r}$ and then apply L'Hopital. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, the limit seems to exist and is 0.

Comment: Yes, you are correct!